# Missing nativeInit when compiling multimple files

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := pacman
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
        Pacman.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In main.cpp:

```
void Java_com_wiagames_pacman_PacmanRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env) {
...
}
```

The package is com.wiagames.pacman; The Java class, containing the nativeInit method, is PacmanRenderer in the com.wiagames.pacman package.
It works fine before I added pacman.cpp, but after adding it I have:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1104
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.wiagames.pacman.PacmanRenderer.nativeInit:()V
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238):    at com.wiagames.pacman.PacmanRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238):    at com.wiagames.pacman.PacmanRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2238):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
W/ActivityManager(  306):   Force finishing activity com.wiagames.pacman/.MainActivity
```

main.c:
http://pastebin.com/GPexqwcv

MainActivity.java:
http://pastebin.com/yWfWpyNb

Comment: May be there is a problem with building of Pacman.cpp and that's misleading you?

Comment: But the library builds successfully.

Comment: it would be much easier to help you if you provided more code, especially the Java class that loads the native library.

Comment: Added links to main.c and MainActivity.java to the post.

Comment: Note that the `C` declaration of nativeInit is wrong. Static JNI methods receive not only `JNIEnv* env`, but also `jclass clazz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right linkage you might try declaring the JNI methods like so:

```
extern "C"                                                                                                              
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_wiagames_pacman_PacmanRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    ...
}
```

(Is it possible that you also changed from C to C++ in introducing `Pacman.cpp` to the project?  That might explain why it stopped working.)

Comment: I also believe this is the root of the problem. `Android.mk` refers to `main.cpp`, but pastebin shows `main.c`.

Comment: No, the file name is main.cpp (main.c is only on the pastebin)